# TV that you can turn off the screen while still listening to audio

Tags: hdtv, energy-efficient, 4k

I'm interested in purchasing a large 4K TV.

One feature I promised myself I'd check on, before purchasing another television, is the ability to turn the TV's screen off at any time, while still being able to hear the audio.

Sometimes I just want to listen to the TV without watching it, and I'd like to save energy during these times (by turning off the screen).

Is this feature offered? Ideally, I'd like it to be a button on the remote control, so I don't have to navigate through a bunch of menus to toggle the screen on and off.

Comment: How are you getting the signal to the television? If its out of a cable box you could always get an inexpensive soundbar/sound system (which you'll probably want anyway considering how lackluster most TV speakers are these days) and run your audio through that device first. Then you could just turn the TV off while keeping your sound system on. That would give you your one button solution, and it would also allow you to purchase a TV without tying yourself down to that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this feature is offered, as for a remote option, I'm not sure.

I owned a Panasonic Viera TC-65AX800U, which was purchased in 2014.  It was a 65" 4K LED model.  This option was located in a separate "Format" sub-menu, not the main picture options menu (contrast, brightness, etc).  I've owned many TV's over the last 10 years or so, and this is the only one that had it.  The others were LG, Visio, another Panasonic, and Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

I own a Samsung JU6050 which offers this feature.

However it does not have a button on the remote, but maybe I just don't know it has. This TV also offers smart features like youtube, which makes this option quite usable. However in my opinion the menu reacts quite slow, but it never crashed or so. It just needs some time.

Maybe the higher end models of Samsung offer this feature to and react faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Roku TV: Steps to Turn Off Screen While Listening to TV**

1. Press the `*` button, on the Roku remote.
2. Select `Picture Off` from the menu.

**Unsummarized**

I just discovered that I can accomplish "turning off the screen" (while listening to TV) on **Roku TVs**.

This probably won't work on external Roku devices (please comment otherwise), but it definitely does work on some (if not all) TVs that use Roku as their built-in "smart tv" operating system.

The steps my vary, but I'll explain what the steps were for me.

While watching an Antenna TV Channel (or a YouTube video, for example) if I press the `*` button on the Roku remote, a menu comes up on the left side of the screen. In that menu, there is an option called `Picture Off`.

If you select `Picture Off`, you'll continue to hear the TV, but the display is **turned off**. After going into this mode, to turn the screen back on (later), you simply press the `OK` button (on the Roku remote) and the screen will turn back `ON` as before.

Simple. I love this feature.